# Postgresql ssl connection through python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl

I found below link

http://python.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.0/driver.html#connection-keywords

it says...

```
import postgresql.driver as pg_driver
```

is the way to import

i used -

```
import postgresql.driver as pg_driver
pg_driver.connect(user = self.username, password = self.password, host = self.host, port = self.port,sslmode = 'verify-full', sslrootcert=self.ssl_cert)
```

but it gives 'ImportError: No module named postgresql.driver'

i tried 'pip install postgresql'
but it gives 'Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement postgresql
No distributions at all found for postgresql'

how can i fixed that ???

Comment: I tend to favour using psycopg2 myself...

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest version of `py-postgresql` and use `'Python34\python.exe setup.py install'` to install it.

You can check `Python34\Lib\site-packages\` if there is a folder called `postgresql` which proves it's installed correctly. Then try `import postgresql.driver as pg_driver` again and tell me if it works.